# Print an assoicated array in a user friendly format

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in my code that I want to print out on a webpage, the arrays hold search engine results, here are the structures of the foreach loops

This loop returns the url,title,snippet and score

```
foreach ($js->RESULT as $item)
{   
    $blekkoArray[str_replace ($find, '', ($item->{'url'}))] = array(         
    'title'=> $item->{'url_title'},
    'snippet' => $item->{'snippet'},
    'score' => $score--
     );

}
```

This loop is used for combining two arrays and creating a ranked list

```
foreach($googleArray as $key=>$value)
{ 
    if(isset($combined[$key]))
    $combined[$key]["score"] += $value['score']; 
    else
    $combined[$key] = array("score"=>$value['score'],"title"=>$value["title"], "snippet"=>$value["snippet"]); 
}
```

I know I can use print_r to print arrays but its not very user friendly, I would also like to href the urls as clickable links, any ideas would be gratefully appreciated.

The arrays prints out

```
Array ( [red.com/] => Array ( [score] => 197 [title] => blah blah....[snippet] more blah blah )
```

Array ( [green.com/] => Array ( [score] => 196 [title] => blah blah....[snippet] more blah blah )

So I would like it to look like how a conventional search engine displays results, I don't need the score to be displayed

Comment: There is no bulit-in method to print arrays, that is "user friendly".  You're gonna need to loop and create some HTML to show your array.

Comment: It is not clear enough what you want. So what is the output you would like to see, also can you post a sample of the array and maybe the ouput you got now by using these foreach loops

Comment: In the PHP documentation for print_r, there are comments that include alternative versions of displaying arrasy.  I'm sure you can find something in there that is close to what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function I found on a blog a while ago that works for me. I don't remember where I found it, or I would credit them with it. See if this does what you need it to. It may not be perfect, but may help you find the keys you need, then you can modify this to print out what you need. Often with arrays I have trouble determining the structure enough to write my foreach loops, and this helps with that.

```
function listArrayRecursive($array_name, $ident = 0){
if (is_array($array_name)){
    foreach ($array_name as $k => $v){
        if (is_array($v)){
            for ($i=0; $i < $ident * 10; $i++){ echo "&nbsp;"; }
            echo $k . " : " . " | ";
            listArrayRecursive($v, $ident + 1);
        }else{
            for ($i=0; $i < $ident * 10; $i++){ echo "&nbsp;"; }
            echo $k . " : " . $v . " | ";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "Variable = " . $array_name;
}
}
```